# Equally Distributing Light On a Quad Object 2D - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, background, lighting

I am using a directional light in order to light up my background for my 2D game. I am using a quad because I need this background to repeat and thus I am using offset to be as efficient as possible. However, the light does not seem to de distributed evenly. I want the background to be bright, but adding a directional light creates a center of light on my background. This is not what I want. I want the light to be evenly distributed over this background. How would I go about this?

Here is a picture to give you a fuller description of what I am talking about:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the background to be bright, but adding a directional light
>   creates a center of light on my background.

Directional light is not good for something like this. I suggest you disabled or remove the Directional light.

You have 2 options to fix this:

**1**.Ambient light

**2**.Material Emissive

Since you are using the Standard shader, Enable Emission on the material then change the Emission color to white to make the image brighter.

[image]

I recommend you go with **#2** since you don't need extra processing power that is required when you use light so **#2** is the best option for you.

All the other lights can be found in the *GameObject* --> *Light* menu. You can read more about each one [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Lighting.html).

Comment: Yes this worked! I added the texture in the box beside color and this gave me my desired effect. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, you can use Texture map for the Color too instead of the changing the color on the emission. Glad I was able to help.